# Changing variable by html button

Tags: javascript, html, var

I'm learning javascript and I decided to create simple Rock, Paper, Scissors game. I want to make it controllable by buttons. So I made this in html:

```
<div id="game">
    <button onClick="user(rock)">Rock</button>
    <button onClick="user(paper)">Paper</button>
    <button onClick="user(scissors)">Scissors</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button onClick="test()">DEBUG</button>
</div>
```

and this in .js file.

```
var user = "none";
function user(choice){
    var user = choice;
}

function test(click){
    alert("You chose " + user);
}
```

So I thought that after I click Rock button it will change var user to rock but it doesn't. After I click rock and then Debug button I get "You chose none".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<div id="game">
    <button onClick="choose('rock')">Rock</button>
    <button onClick="choose('paper')">Paper</button>
    <button onClick="choose('scissors')">Scissors</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button onClick="test()">DEBUG</button>
</div>
```

and

```
var user;
function choose(choice){
    user = choice;
}

function test(click){
    alert("You chose " + user);
}
```

Comment: This one helped me a lot. I found a mistake. :)

Answer (score 4):

`var` is used for declaring a variable. You don't need to declare `user` variable again in `user` function. You just need to assign a value to declared one.

```
var user; //declaration
function user(choice) {
    user = choice; //assignment
}
```

Comment: I did it same way you typed it and I still get "none" from debug button.

Answer (score 2):

One problem:

```
var user = "none";
function user(choice){
    var user = choice;
}
```

One variable of user is hiding the other variable of user.

And having a function and variable with the same name is a BAD idea.

Answer (score 1):

The [`var`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript) keyword used in the scope of a function will declare a new local variable.

Hence, in the global scope, `user` retains the value `"none"`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this.. cleaner markup.. uses jQuery

```
<div id="game">
    <button class="user" data-name="rock">Rock</button>
    <button class="user" data-name="paper">Paper</button>
    <button class="user" data-name="scissors">Scissors</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button id="test">DEBUG</button>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
    var user = "none";
    $(".user").click(function() {
       user = $(this).attr("data-name");
    });

    $("#test").click(function() {
       alert(user);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rQDbe/

Comment: Thank you. I don't wanna use jQuerry yet. I'm learning javascript right now and after that I wanna learn jQuerry. :)

Comment: good to know this :) you should learn JavaScript before you use a library.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a scoping issue. Try removing the var inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are fixing some issues. There is also a problem with the way you're calling the functions as you're passing `rock` as a variable, you need to use a string:

```
<button onClick="user('rock')">Rock</button>
```

Unless you're declaring the variables somewhere but it's not shown in your code.

Comment: I fixed that. Now it's as you say:

`<button onClick="user("rock")">Rock</button>

        <button onClick="user("paper")">Paper</button>

        <button onClick="user("scissors")">Scissors</button>`

Comment: Don't use double quotes for the string in the attributes or this won't work

Comment: Ahh that was the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The selections should be encased in the quotes, javascript is looking for the variables named paper etc.

```
<button onClick="user(rock)">Rock</button>
<button onClick="user(paper)">Paper</button>
<button onClick="user(scissors)">Scissors</button>
```